# javaws name too long

Tags: java-web-start, icedtea

I am trying to use iced tea / javaws to authenticate as user at the [USPTO](https://efs.uspto.gov/TruePassWebStart/AuthenticationChooser.html) (patent/trademark office).  I download the jnlp file and try to use it with javaws but hit a 'name too long' error  -  does anyone know how to work around this?

```
jeremy@jeremy-Blade ~/Downloads $ javaws uspto-auth.authenticate.jnlp 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/jeremy/.cache/icedtea-web/cache/0/https/efs.uspto.gov/TruePassWebStart/uspto-auth.authenticate.jnlp.q_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_.info (File name too long)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.util.PropertiesFile.store(PropertiesFile.java:167)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.CacheEntry.store(CacheEntry.java:225)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceDownloader.initializeFromURL(ResourceDownloader.java:193)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceDownloader.initializeOnlineResource(ResourceDownloader.java:128)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceDownloader.initializeResource(ResourceDownloader.java:118)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceDownloader.run(ResourceDownloader.java:107)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```